# give permission to acces /var/run/docker.sock on synology nas

Tags: docker, permissions, nas, synology

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/) to setup traefik properly on my DS918+. Everything seems to work normally but I can't actually launch it because

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock: 
Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/traefik/logs?follow=1&stderr=1&stdout=1&tail=100&timestamps=1: 
dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I have tried `sudo chmod +rwx docker.sock` with the user that I'm using to launch the docker but to no avail.

How should I solve this ?

Comment: The guide is huge and it is unclear at which step you are getting this error. Have you tried launching your service using `sudo` or adding your user / service account to the `docker` linux group? If you or your service account are in `docker` group, you will be able to connect to docker socket.

Answer (score 0):

The guide is huge and it is unclear at which step you are getting this error. Have you tried launching your service using `sudo` or adding your user / service account to the `docker` linux group? If you or your service account are in `docker` group, you will be able to connect to docker socket.